# Sort JIRA backlog by ticket# asc/DESC?

Tags: jira, product, jira-agile

I've been absolutely stumped on how to sort our backlog by our ticket#, IE: EX-100, EX-101, EX-1000, EX-2000 etc. Any idea how to do this? I tried via the quick-filters through: project = "Example" ORDER BY key ASC. I'm stumped.

Comment: If you are just looking at the standard page, clicking any of the column headers will sort by it, so just clicking on the Key header should have it work. If you are handling your request through the advanced options remember to use the project handle, not the full name (i.e Example Item = EI) so { project = EI ORDER BY key ASC } would be the actual input to the advanced standard

Answer (score 1):

If EX is the key of your project, enter this URL for API requests:

```
https://<yourJIRAurlhere>/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%20EX%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20ASC
```

Sometimes the results don't come back due to `%20` not being included.

If you are using the Advanced Search option within JIRA, then the following should work (use the project key instead of the project name):

```
project = EX ORDER BY key ASC
```